# Click through div?

Tags: css

I know that you can use `pointer-events: none` to make the effect of being able to click through a div. But, this also erases any hover effects as well. Is there a way to preserve the hover effects while still being able to click through the div?

Edit: This is a link of what I'm trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/VanillaLore/7xx2qpam/1/
When you hover over one div, the brown div behind it gets shorter (from `height: 200px;` to `height: 10px;`)
It reveals another block underneath. I want that block to spin on hover, but there's still a div on top of it.
(I don't want to remove the first one because I need something to stay at height: 200px; so that the brown block doesn't regrow when I'm not hovering over the 10px but over the other 190px) I hope that explains it.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? maybe there's a better way to do so

Comment: Try this once: `backface-visibility: hidden;`